# If $(\cdots A_{i_3}A_{i_2}A_{i_1})x_0\to 0$ for some $x_0$, what happens for any other $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis

Assume you have $m$ non-singular matrices $A_1,\dots,A_m$ and a given sequence of numbers $\{i_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ for which $i_k\in\{1,\dots,m\}$. Also assume that you know that for some particular vector $x_0$ with $\|x_0\|=1$ you obtain
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(A_{i_N}\cdots A_{i_1}\right)x_0=0
$$
My question is if you can conclude the same for any other vector $x$ with $\|x\|=1$ using the same sequence $\{i_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$.

Comment: For an obvious counter-example take $A_i=A$ for all $i$ and $x_0 \in Ker (A)$.

Comment: I am very sorry, I forgot to add the non-singular condition. I was just reviewing the question. Also, why did I got the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are simple counter-examples. Suppose $Ax_0=\frac  1 2 x_0$ and $Ay=y$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$. Take $A_i=A$ for all $i$ and you have  a counter-example.

Comment: Nice, I think this clears it up. Thanks!